# Solution collection java using gurobi

Tags: java, collections, gurobi

I am struggling as newby with collecting solutions in java. The problem entails a mixed-integer linear problem in which i have to collect multiple solutions. I use gurobi for the optimalisation and we should get multiple solutions for the decision variables. I am using the Solutioncollection that is given below for this. In the solution class the solution is retrieved and makes it possible to set an objective value. My question is how do i get different values for the decision variables. Till now I have the following code in the optimizer and the solution collection below:

```
    CLSPSolutionCollection collection = new CLSPSolutionCollection ();
    CLSPSolution sol = new CLSPSolution (K,T);

        model.optimize();

        // 6. determine production quantities, setups and overtime ----------------------------------------------------------

        if (model.get(GRB.IntAttr.Status) == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL) {


            int s = model.get(GRB.IntAttr.SolCount);
            model.set(GRB.IntParam.SolutionNumber, s);

            sol.setObjectiveValue((int) model.get(GRB.DoubleAttr.ObjNVal)); // produce result
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
                for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {
                    sol.setProductionQuantity(k, t, q[k][t].get(GRB.DoubleAttr.Xn));    // set decision variable q
                    sol.setSetupDecision(k, t, gamma[k][t].get(GRB.DoubleAttr.Xn)); // set decision variable Q
                    sol.setOvertimeDecision(t, beta[t].get(GRB.DoubleAttr.Xn)); // set decision variable Q


                //collection.add();
                }}
            }

        // if


        // clean up ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        model.dispose();  
        env.dispose();

    } catch ( GRBException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // catcher in the rye

    return collection;
```

// COLLECTION CLASS
public class CLSPSolutionCollection {

```
private ArrayList<CLSPSolution> solutions;

public CLSPSolutionCollection ( ) {
    // TODO
} // constructor
//TODO .. 

public void add ( CLSPSolution solution ) { 
    solutions.add(solution);
} // add

public int size ( ) {
    return solutions.size();
} // size

public CLSPSolution get ( int index ) {
    return solutions.get(index);
} // get
```

} // CLSPSolutionCollection